# Kernel options required for the installation of Systemtap

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-10.10, systemtap

I want to install kerneltap in ubuntu. I want to know whether if I need to recompile the kernel again then which options should I turn on in the kernel during recompilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Systemtap has worked fine on the basic Ubuntu kernels for some time.  The challenge is locating the stripped debugging information that matches the exact kernel version you run.  http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/SystemtapOnUbuntu